# Join in Pandas similar to SQL Inner Join

Tags: python, pandas, join

My first dataset is in the tsv format

```
Id  Val1    Val2
0   1   2
1   2   3
2   3   5
3   1   3
```

Second Dataset in the form

```
Id  Val3
0   3
2   5
```

I have to join both datasets on the Column Id to give the output as

```
Id  Val1    Val2    Val3
0   1   2   3
2   3   5   5
```

How do I achieve this in pandas?

Comment: You can achieve that by reading the docs!  Specifically on merging etc:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: err.. did you look at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging)? specifcally `pd.merge(lhs, rhs, on='Id', how='inner')`?

Comment: @JohnE Thankfully, there's a [doc-style dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) you can use to close questions like these now.

Comment: @coldspeed  ah, thanks, good to know (although I'm not very active here nowadays but I bookmarked it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [df.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

You probably want to set `df.merge(df2, on='Id', how='inner')`

Comment: Note that the default is `how='inner'`.

Comment: That's a valid point ;)

Answer (score 0):

In pandas you JOIN using the MERGE function.

With your initial dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Id": [0,1,2,3], "Val1": [1,2,3,1], "Val2": [2,3,5,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Id": [0,2], "Val3": [3,5]})
```

You do the inner join with pd.merge():

```
df = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how='inner')

df
Id  Val1    Val2    Val3
0   1   2   3
2   3   5   5
```